# Editing word text box with python

Tags: python, text, ms-word, docx

I have the following problem: I am trying to edit a word document using python. I am able to change a placeholder to the desired text when it is in paragraph form, but I can't edit the place holder in a text box. I have tried docx win32com etc. but I am really struggling to get it to work. What would the best method be for performing both these task? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Edit: I see I am using it to edit an inline shape. I need it to edit a floating shape, and I think this is what is causing the issue. I am still struggling to edit the floating shape with docx.

```
        doc = Document(docx_file_path)

        # Get the corresponding name from name_list
        investor_index = list(number_dictionary.keys()).index(investor_number)
        corresponding_name = name_list[investor_index]

        # Find and replace text within text boxes
        for shape in doc.inline_shapes:
            if shape.type == 3:  # Check if shape is a text box
                textbox = shape.text_frame
                for paragraph in textbox.paragraphs:
                    if "Placeholder1" in paragraph.text:
                        for run in paragraph.runs:
                            if "Placeholder1" in run.text:
                                run.text = run.text.replace("Placeholder1", corresponding_name)
                                run.font.name = 'Abhaya Libre'
                                run.font.size = Pt(14)

        # Find and replace text "Placeholder3" with "Dear {corresponding name from name_list},"
        for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
            if "Placeholder3" in paragraph.text:
                for run in paragraph.runs:
                    if "Placeholder3" in run.text:
                        run.text = run.text.replace("Placeholder3", f"Dear {corresponding_name},")
                        # Set font and size for the replaced text
                        run.font.name = 'Abhaya Libre'
                        run.font.size = Pt(14)

        # Save the modified document
        doc.save(destination_path)
```